# React: Remove current instance of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am using a map to display multiple components on my page:

```
<ul>
    {this.props.userComponents.map((userComponent, index) => {
        return <UserComponent key={index} {...userComponent} />
    })}
</ul>
```

In my address component, I want to include a button that can delete the instance of the component:

```
const UserComponent = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Media body>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Button onClick={ /*function here should remove the component */ }>Delete</Button>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Media>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Pass the function to delete the instance as a prop to your `<UserComponent>`?

Comment: in props pass function and call onclick of that button